# How do I make the navigationBar appear on top in React Native

Tags: react-native

I was testing out the `Navigator` component and I was trying to use its `navigationBar` property. I want it to appear on top of the "content" instead of below it, the only way I found to do that is by using position absolute, but that way I need to set the top of the "content" as well (requiring me to make a fixed height `navigationBar` plus unnecessary boilerplate code). Is there any other way to do this?